# user input from shell script using read

Tags: shell

I'm a shell noob and trying to write a simple script that will search for files and perform some function and the moment just printing the results. Where i'm confused is, the last two commands. The command `find . -type f -name "*.py" -print0`  executes exactly like it does on the command line.

When I try to add the user read substitution with `$filepattern` adding in `"*.py"` while running the script the input of `"*.py"` get's transformed into `'"*.py"'` but if i enter `*.py` it only matches the first file it finds. What am i missing here? Why does `*.py` match one file and `"*.py"` get's transferred into a string?

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x #echo on
echo "File pattern to look for? (eg '*.txt')"
read filepattern

echo "i am echoing $filepattern"
find . -type f -name $filepattern -print0
find . -type f -name "*.py" -print0
```

Comment: I think you are getting confused by the extra messaged caused by `set -x #echo on`. Those messages are just for display and aren't affecting your `find`. I recommend removing the `set` line as you `echo` the information already.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `find` option with quotes `... -name "$filepattern" ...`?

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

read -p "File pattern to look for? (eg '*.txt'): " -r filepattern

echo "i am echoing '$filepattern'"
find . -type f -name "$filepattern" -print0
```